# Show inequality about riemann integrals with jensen inequality

Tags: inequality, riemann-integration, jensen-inequality

I am having trouble proving the following inequality:

Let $f,h: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $h >0$ and $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and convex. Show that:
$$
\phi(\frac{\int^1 _0 f(x) h(x) dx}{\int _0 ^1 h(y) dy}) \leq \frac{\int^1 _0 \phi(f(x)) h(x) dx}{\int _0 ^1 h(y) dy}
$$
We are supposed to use the general mean value theorem for integrals and the fact that:
$ \phi(\int_0 ^1 f(x) dx) \leq \int_0 ^1 \phi(f(x)) dx$. Furthermore we can assume that for a segmentation $0=x_0, \ldots x_n=1$ it holds that for:
$\alpha_k := \frac{\int_{x_k} ^{x_{k+1}} h(x) dx}{\int_0 ^1 h(y) dy}$
$\alpha_k > 0$ and $\sum_{k=0} ^{n-1} \alpha_k = 1$.

However the last thing seems quite trivial to me and not that useful.

So far I (think that I) was able to show that:
$$
\phi(\frac{\int^1 _0 f(x) h(x) dx}{\int _0 ^1 h(y) dy}) = \phi(\frac{f(\xi) \int^1 _0 h(x) dx}{\int _0 ^1 h(y) dy}) = \phi(f(\xi))
$$
(For some $\xi \in [0,1]$ with the mean value theorem).
However I don't know whether that's useful or not. Any tips/help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\xi$ ?

Comment: A way to solve it if to consider  $x \to \frac{h(x)}{\int _0 ^1 h(y)dy}$ and probaility density function and then apply Jensen for probability density function. Consider and more general measure based on the PDF to demonstrate it. See here e.g 1.51 https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html.